# Variable not defined after enumerating glob.glob object

Tags: python, glob

I currently have this code:

```
os.listdir("V:/FM003")
results = pd.DataFrame([])
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("F5331_FM003**")):
    namedf = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0], skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],  
    index_col=[0], usecols= [0,1])
    results = results.append(namedf)
print(namedf)
```

It keeps returning the error "name 'namedf' is not defined". Can anyone help me with how to write it correctly please? I'm a little stumped.

Comment: Consider what would happen if no files matched the glob pattern.  `namedf` would not be defined, so initialise it with a default before your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

> **glob.glob**(*pathname, *, recursive=False*)
>
> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which
>   must be a **string containing a path specification**.

A reliable way to build such a path specification is to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html):

```
import os

folder = r'V:/FM003'
files = r'F5331_FM003**'
paths = os.path.join(folder, files)

for counter, file in enumerate(paths):
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

actually I think your problem is that your glob is not accessing the correct folder. Hence no such file is found.

Assuming that you are looking for files in the directory V:/FM003, you might consider using:

```
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("V:/FM003/F5331_FM003**")):
```

Answer (score -1):

You defined the "namedf" inside the for loop and printing it outside the for loop.
Just write your print statement in the same scope.

```
os.listdir("V:/FM003")
results = pd.DataFrame([])
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("F5331_FM003**")):
    namedf = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0], skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],  
    index_col=[0], usecols= [0,1])
    results = results.append(namedf)
    print(namedf)
```

Comment: For loop does not delete variable created inside the scope